# Vue/Nuxt hot-loading is taking a long time

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

Recently I realize that my Nuxt app is taking super long for the hotloading. Even just for a one line change it will take around 50 seconds to hot load on average. Do you know what might be the problem for this? I'm not sure whether it's a hardware issue or something else.[image]

Answer (score -2):

Delete the **node_modules** folder.

Run the `npm install` command.

Try again with `npm run dev`.